# parallel haskell (ghc 6.10.4) doesn't accept -N greater than -N1

Tags: multithreading, haskell, parallel-processing, multicore

I'm trying to run parallel code in GHC 6.10.4 (from MacPorts) on OS X 10.5

I'm building with -threaded, in my makefile:

```
GHC=ghc -prof -auto-all -O -threaded

glicko: glicko.hs Lib.hs
        $(GHC) --make -main-is Glicko glicko.hs lib.hs
```

When I invoke `./glicko +RTS -N` or `./glicko +RTS -N1` the code runs, but seems to only use one CPU. If i invoke as `./glicko +RTS -N2`, then I am given the runtime help message that documents commandline parameters; but the documentation suggests that this should run the program.

Why is -N2 not working?

Here's more time info:

```
$ ./glicko +RTS --info
 [("GHC RTS", "YES")
 ,("GHC version", "6.10.4")
 ,("RTS way", "rts_thr_p")
 ,("Host platform", "i386-apple-darwin")
 ,("Host architecture", "i386")
 ,("Host OS", "darwin")
 ,("Host vendor", "apple")
 ,("Build platform", "i386-apple-darwin")
 ,("Build architecture", "i386")
 ,("Build OS", "darwin")
 ,("Build vendor", "apple")
 ,("Target platform", "i386-apple-darwin")
 ,("Target architecture", "i386")
 ,("Target OS", "darwin")
 ,("Target vendor", "apple")
 ,("Word size", "32")
 ,("Compiler unregisterised", "NO")
 ,("Tables next to code", "YES")
 ]
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to use the Mac binary installer for GHC 6.12.3 (lastest Haskell Platform?) Parallel performance is significantly better.

Comment: only that one is already installed on my laptop and the other isn't.

Do you know anything to suggest that that would affect this? (rather than "its broken. try a different version." ?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> RTS way", "rts_thr_p"

You have compiled with both *profiling* and *threading*. The profiler only works in multicore mode with 1 cpu (the profiling data structures in the runtime aren't threadsafe yet).

Compile your program without profiling, and you will be able to use more than -N1.

See [ticket #886](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/886)